# I am getting linker errors when using clock_gettime

Tags: linux, linker-errors, standard-library, gettickcount

To use `clock_gettime` what library do I need to link with? I am getting linker errors that `clock_gettime` is undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try linking to `librt`:

```
gcc -o myprog myprog.c -lrt
```

(also note that you have to put the `-lrt` flag after specifying the `myprog.c` source file!)

Comment: You just need to put `-lrt` *after* `myprog.c` and you could put `-o myprog` at last.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch that's true.